# How to not repeat "obj." when invoking many methods on the same object?

Tags: javascript

I don't remember where I saw that you can replace calls like this:

```
my_obj.method_1();
my_obj.method_2();
my_obj.method_3();
```

With something like this:

```
some_construct (my_obj) {
    method_1();
    method_2();
    method_3();
}
```

Any idea on how to do this?

*Note: I'm not looking for method chaining*

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: Got many useful answers, the `with` is what I was looking for. I'm just being cusrious, I won't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct is

```
with (my_obj) {
    ...
}
```

but **don't use it**! It's deprecated, since it makes it hard to see whether a name refers to an object property or a variable, and the check must be made repeatedly at runtime. `"use strict";` actually prohibits `with`.

If you don't want to type as much, you can give the object you're using a shorter name:

```
o = my_obj;
o.method_1();
o.method_2();
o.method_3();
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), but don't do it. It's [confusing syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Ambiguity_contra) at best, and is banned in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (which you should be using).

```js
var my_obj = {
  value: 0,
  foo: function() {
    this.value++
  },
  bar: function() {
    this.value += 2
  },
  baz: function() {
    alert(this.value)
  }
};

with(my_obj) {
  foo();
  bar();
  baz();
}
```

Comment: I have just been hunting for this. Well remembered!

Answer (score 1):

In modern JavaScript there's no syntactic sugar for this.

At the end of the day, object-oriented programming doesn't like not being able to know to which object instance belongs a member by just reading the code.

### The right way

There's a concept in object-oriented programming called *encapsulation*. If you need to simplify your code because you don't want to call a set of methods that should be called together, you need to encapsulate these calls into a more generic method:

```
var obj = {
    method1: function() {}, method2: function(), method3: function(),
    doAll: function() {
         this.method1();
         this.method2();
         this.method3();
    }
};
```

And later you just call `obj.doAll()` instead of each method one by one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're goal is to "conserve" text, you could:

```js
function callAll(o, funcs) {
  funcs.forEach(function(func) {
    o[func]();
    });
}

// Have an object...
var my_obj = {
  method1: function() {
    alert(1);
  },
  method2: function() {
    alert(2);
  },
  method3: function() {
    alert(3);
  }
}

// And now you can call multiple object methods like this:
callAll(my_obj, ['method1', 'method2', 'method3']);
```

So basically you have 1 short function that you can invoke with an object and a list of method names to call.